# Python program: how to get key strokes from terminal?

Tags: python

I am writing a Python script, run from Ubuntu terminal, that takes commands in a certain format and does tasks for me. Meaning the script prints "> " and reads a command, executes it, and then returns to the beginning. I would like a implement a feature in which pressing the up arrow causes the previous command to appear on my command line, similar to the bash command line. How can I implement this?

Comment: Can someone hint why my post was downvoted? I am not aware of any rules that I may be breaking.

Answer (score 0):

It is called history. You probably should find a binding of [GNU readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) like [rl](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rl)

Answer (score 0):

As well as the [rl](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rl) module mentioned by Basile Starynkevitch, there's the standard module [readline](https://docs.python.org/2/library/readline.html#module-readline). If you import `readline` into your script you automatically get line editing & history when you use `input()` or `raw_input()` in Python 2. or `input()` in Python 3.

Here's a quick Python 2 demo program that does [Caesar encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher).

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

''' Simple Caesar encryption / decryption of stdio

    Gets shift from command line; default is ROT13

    Written by PM 2Ring 2012.12.01
'''

import sys, readline

lobase = ord('a')
hibase = ord('A')

def rot(c, delta):
    if c.isalpha(): 
        base = lobase if c.islower() else hibase
        c = chr(base + (ord(c) - base + delta) % 26)
    return c

def main():
    delta = int(sys.argv[1]) if len(sys.argv) > 1 else 13

    while True:
        try:
            s = raw_input()
            print ''.join(rot(c, delta) for c in s)
        except EOFError:
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```